# Unity Try/Catch With AssetBundle.LoadFromFile() Does Not Work

Tags: unity-game-engine, exception

I am executing the following method from the Unity Start() method:

```
private void GetFiles()
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    EnumerateFiles(baseDir, ref files);

    foreach (string assetBundleName in files)
    {
        try
        {
            assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(assetBundleName);
            prefabs.Add(assetBundleName, assetBundle.GetAllAssetNames().ToList().Where(s => s.ToUpper().EndsWith(".PREFAB")).ToList());
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        if (assetBundle != null) { assetBundle.Unload(true); }
    }
}
```

I am trying to enumerate through a bunch of asset bundles and look for prefabs. I have no issue getting the list of asset bundles. However, to determine the prefabs inside I need to load the asset bundle and then use something like GetAllAssetNames() to determine the contents. In my case, I look for the asset name ending in Prefab to determine prefabs. The code works fine as long as none of the asset bundles are corrupt.

However, if a asset bundle is corrupt, the application throws a, seemingly uncatchable, exception and ends execution. I have placed the asset bundle load and the GetAllAssetNames() call in a try/catch structure to try to catch such an error and just continue with the next asset bundle but the try/catch does not seem to be able to catch the error.

Any idea how I can catch such an error to prevent the application from crashing?

Comment: The Unity exception seems to trip on the ``assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(assetBundleName);``. As such adding a check to see if assetBundle is null, before using it, will not help.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the `assetBundle.Unload` that is causing the Expections. Because according to the documentation `LoadFromFile` should not throw an Expection, but `Unload` can if you pass false and then attempt to load any more objects from that bundle the operation will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Yes. I am sure. When I run it in the Unity Editor it identifies the line that causes the issue. I think that may actually be *the* issue. It is not throwing a normal exception that could be caught by the try/catch. It seems to be raising a exception in the console log and then halting the method. The application continue to run but the method that includes the LoadFromFile is ended. 

The odd thing is that in another application where I use LoadFromFile, I am able to survive loading a corrupt asset bundle, so it must be something related to the project itself.